# What is the name of the event after changing a page (after using $.mobile.navigate('page-1'))

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wan't to call:

```
  $(document).on('nameOfevent' function(){....
```

after I called to `$.mobile.navigate('page-1')` in a different place

(I have two divs in one HTML file, and in every div I have an attribute of data-role="page".)

what is the name of the event that will be fired after I change a page using the jquery `.navigate` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Description: Triggered on the "toPage" after the transition animation has completed.

jQuery( ".selector" ).on( "pageshow", function( event ) { ... } )

Answer (score 0):

The event name is `navigate`, said jQuery.

```
 $.mobile.navigate( "#page-1", { info: "info about the #page-1 hash" });
```

Then you can hook the event as follows:

```
 $( window ).on( "navigate", function( event, data ) {
    console.log( data.state.info );
    console.log( data.state.direction )
    console.log( data.state.url )
    console.log( data.state.hash )
  });
```

EDITS: `{ info: "info about the #page-1 hash" }` is not required so you may skip it and write `$.mobile.navigate( "#page-1")`; The `navigate` event will fire without data.